# How can I use FolderBrowserDialog in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void btnRadarFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if(result.)
    }
}
```

The first time I tried to use the `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` I got error that Forms don't exist. so I installed the ookii-dialogs-wpf package and once installed the errors are gone but I'm not sure what to do next. The variable result don't have an OK or any properties to continue with the dialog.

When I click the button, it's opening the dialog browser like in the old vista style, but I'm not sure how to handle it in the button/s click event.

Comment: You must install the Windows.Forms.dll. If you don't have it then use NuGet Package Manager to install it.

Comment: Have you reviewed the samples for that package? https://github.com/ookii-dialogs/ookii-dialogs-wpf/blob/master/sample/Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Sample/MainWindow.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

You invoke the Ookii folder browser in a similar way to FolderBrowserDialog, with two main exceptions:

1. The class you instantiate is `VistaFolderBrowserDialog`, not `FolderBrowserDialog`.
2. It returns a `nullable bool` instead of a `DialogResult`.

Here is some sample code:

```
VistaFolderBrowserDialog folderSelector = new() {
    Description = "Description",
    Multiselect = false,
    ShowNewFolderButton = false,
    UseDescriptionForTitle = true
};

bool? result = folderSelector.ShowDialog(parentWindow);
if (result == true) {
    // The OK button was clicked.
} else if (result == false) {
    // The folder selector was closed without clicking the OK button.
} else if (result == null) {
    // Documentation doesn't say when it would return Null. My guess would be if something went wrong.
}
```

And finally, once you have the Ookii browser working, you can remove any references to `Windows.Forms` from your project, as Ookii doesn't need it.